# Extract Address component from given address text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to extract the address component from the given address line on web. A example of address type is given below.

```
CHRIS NISWANDEE
   SMALLSYS INC
   795 E DRAGRAM
   TUCSON AZ 85705
   USA
```

I need to extract the all Address component like zipcode, street no, direction , home number etc from this text by using javascript or jquery.

Please help to resolved my issue, thanks in advance

Comment: Is it plain text or embedded in something like http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard

Answer (score 0):

put it to variable and split it,like this;

```
var str="CHRIS NISWANDEE SMALLSYS INC 795 E DRAGRAM TUCSON AZ 85705 USA";
var strsplit=str.split(" ");
var a=strsplit[0];
.
.
.
var country=strsplit[10];
```

fiddle demo:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DRHTw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If all of the bits of information are to be guaranteed to be on a newline like your example you could split on a new line

```
var ks = str.split("\n");
```